# Using "lea ($30, %edx), %eax to add edx and 30 and put it into eax

Tags: c, assembly

I'm studying for a midterm tomorrow and one of the questions on a previous midterm is:

Consider the following C function. Write the corresponding assembly language function to perform the same operation.

```
int myFunction (int a) 
{ 
    return (a + 30); 
}
```

What I wrote down is:

```
.global _myFunction
_myFunction:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    movl 8(%ebp), %edx
    lea ($30, %edx), %eax
    leave
    ret
```

where a is edx and a+30 would be eax. Is the use of lea correct in this case? Would it instead need to be

```
lea ($30, %edx, 1), %eax
```

Thanks.

Comment: looks like something the compiler would generate, at least.  Any reason, though, that the function isn't just `movl 4(%esp), %eax` `addl $30, %eax` `ret`?  Building a stack frame isn't very useful if you never actually use the stack (ie: unless you call functions yourself, reserve space for locals, etc).

Comment: lea is generally faster than add if you don't need the flags set.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, I actually read otherwise. To my knowledge `lea` prevents instruction reordering, because the flags register need to be populated before the `lea` instruction can be executed. Using `lea` instead of `add` should be a bad idea on any non-ancient CPU.

Comment: @Kay that is correct. However if you look at my comment I said *generally*. Most optimizers will look at context to determine if add or lea make more sense in any given situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to simply add 30 using `leal` then you should do it this way:

```
leal 30(%edx), %eax
```

The notation is `displacement`(`baseregister`, `offsetregister`, `scalarmultiplier`). The displacement is placed on the outside. `30` is added to `edx` and stored in `eax`. In AT&T/GAS notation you can leave off both the offset and multiplier. In our example this leaves us with the equivalent of `base + displacement` or `edx + 30` in this example.

cHao also brings up a good point. Let us say the professor asks you to optimize your code. There are some inefficiencies in the fact that `myFunction` uses no local variables and doesn't need stack space for itself. Because of that all the stack frame creation and destruction can be removed. If you remove the stack frame then you no longer `push %ebp` as well. That means your first parameter `int a` is at `4(%esp)` . With that in mind your function can be reduced to something this simple:

```
.global _myFunction
_myFunction:
    movl 4(%esp), %eax
    addl $30, %eax
    ret
```

Of course the moment you change your function so that it needs to store things on the stack you would have to put the stack frame code back in (`pushl %ebp`, `pushl %ebp`, `leave` etc)

Comment: The multiply part of addressing modes can't be zero: where it exists, it is always one of 1,2,4,8. However, the operand that it applies to is optional.

Comment: base + displacement is a special case. I originally used the word "effectively" since from the observers perspective the lack of offsetregister(index) and multiplier will *appear* to equate to zero. Under the hood `base + displacement` results in a special one byte address mode encoding that specifies neither the offsetregister(index) nor the multiplier. *Obviously* a side effect is that an assembler won't allow you to specify any scalar without an offsetregister(index)  If you don't specify the offsetregister no scalarmultiplier at all is encoded into the instruction.